# Java Database "insert into" syntax error

Tags: java, database, sqlanywhere, insert-into

In my java program i'm trying to insert users into my database only if not exists but when i insert java catch exception anyway. Here is the code

```
public void UserToDB(Registered registered) throws SQLException{
    Connection conn = SimpleDataSource.getConnection();

  try
  {
     PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO User(ID,Email,Name,LastName,Password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)"
                                                    + "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from User WHERE Email = ?)");
     stat.setInt(1,registered.getId());
     stat.setString(2,registered.getEmail());
     stat.setString(3,registered.getName());
     stat.setString(4,registered.getLastName());
     stat.setString(5,registered.getPassword());
     stat.setString(6,registered.getEmail());
     stat.executeUpdate();      
  }catch(SQLException e){
      System.out.println("Error: Email already exists");
  }
  finally
  {
     conn.close();
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

`Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from User WHERE Email = '4444@hotmail.com')' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
    at social_network.DBManager.UserToDB(DBManager.java:51)
    at social_network.Social_Network.main(Social_Network.java:36)`

How can i fix?

Comment: Stack trace please :)

Comment: Btw you are throwing and catching exception at the same time?

Comment: what are your primary, unique keys?

Comment: The `insert` statement does not have a `where` condition.

Comment: my primary key is Email and ID

Comment: Please copy and paste the entire stack trace so that we can see the that error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT INTO does not support the WHERE clause. So the issue is not actually with the EXISTS clause.

WHERE is for filtering rows. You don't want to filter rows. You want to insert rows. It seems to me that what you actually want to do is upsert rows in the `User` table based on the presence of a given email value. For this, check the MERGE INTO statement.

Comment: so how should i write my query?

Answer (score 0):

Insert statements do not support the where clause.. Try to use joints

Comment: so how should i write my query?